# webpack html-loader and MiniCssExtractPlugin

Tags: javascript, webpack, mini-css-extract-plugin, webpack-html-loader

I'm using setup from getting-started webpack page:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Development',
      template: 'src/index.html'
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
  ],
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    clean: true //clean dist folder before each build
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: 'html-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

And this one works OK if I include `import './style.css';` at the top of `src/index.js`. Inside of the produced `dest/index.html` I get the line where the extracted CSS style is generated as `<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">`.

Now what I want is to remove that line `import './style.css';` at the top of `src/index.js` and use instead of that one `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">` that I will place inside the template `src/index.html`.

When doing this, generated `dest/index.html` gets correctly the line `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="b88d04fba731603756b1.css">` and the file `dest/b88d04fba731603756b1.css` is generated, but it's content is wrong as I get this instead of real css styles:

```
// extracted by mini-css-extract-plugin
export {};
```

Is there a way to use `html-loader` plugin together with `MiniCssExtractPlugin`, so that I do not need to import css inside js files but instead import it inside html template?